# Binary Arithmetic with non-standard representation in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to do binary operations in Prolog for a homework assignment. I'm not looking for copy-paste answers but I'm really stuck and any pointers would be greatly appreciated. The numbers are defined with f0 = 0 and f1 = 1, from least to most significant digit, i.e.:

```
f0(f0(f1(null))) = 100 = 4
f1(f1(null)) = 11 = 3
f0(f1(f0(null)) = 010 = 2 (this is considered an "illegal" number because of the trailing zeroes)
```

The requirements are:

1. Define predicate incr(P1,P2) such that P2 is the successor to P1
2. Define predicate legal(P) true exactly of legal Pterms (excluding null and anything with leading zeroes)
3. Using legal/2, revise incr to incrR such that incrR(X,Y) lists all numbers in order.
4. Define predicate add(P1,P2,P3) such that P3 = P1+P2

I have working predicates for 1-3, and my add/3 works to verify values true or false, but it is failing to find P3 when given P1 and P2 (i.e. add(something,something,X) is non-terminating). I'm not sure if my add is wrong, or if there are problems in my previous predicates not allowing me

We are not allowed to use lists or in-built arithmetic for this as we haven't covered them yet. My current knowledge base is as follows:

```
% Question 1

incr(f1(null),f0(f1(null))).
incr(f1(X),f0(Ans)) :- incr(X,Ans).
incr(f0(X),f1(X)).

% Question 2

legal(f0(null)).
legal(X) :- legal(A), incr(A,X).

% Question 3

incrR(X,Y) :- legal(X), incr(X,Y).

% Question 4

add(f0(null),X,X).
add(P1,P2,P3) :- incrR(A,P1), incrR(B,P3), add(A,P2,B).
```

I've been struggling with this for a few days and haven't found anything to help me online, so I thought I'd ask here as a hail mary. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: For 4. As you remove a functor for one, add a functor to the other. When there are not more functors to remove you are done.

Comment: Of interest: [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do the addition in the same manner in which you'd do decimal arithmetic long hand. Beginning with the least significant digit (the "one's place"):

- Add each digit together. The resulting value is the sum modulo the base of the numbering system in use (10 for decimal, 2 for binary). The *carry* is the result of integer division by the base.
- Move to the next most significant digit, include the carry as a value to be summed.
- Repeat until you run out of digits.

Your nested data structure has the least significant digit first, so that actually simplifies things a bit.

A common pattern in Prolog is the use of *helper* predicates, that have some additional arguments that carry the state neccessary for the computation. Here, that additional state would be the carry.

That leads us to this:

You'll notice that the the result is built up as we go, as an *open* data structure, where its content is unbound, and is finally *closed* only once the digits of both numbers have been exhausted.

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------
% add/3: add two binary numbers, X and Y, yielding the sum as Z
%----------------------------------------------------------------
add( X, Y, Z ) :- add(f0,X,Y,Z) . % invoke the helper with an initial carry of zero

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
% add/4: compute the sum of two binary numbers, X and Y, digit-by-digit with a carry,
% yielding Z as the result.
%
% add( Carry , X , Y , Sum  ) .
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

% these clauses are the terminating cases
add( f0 , null  , null  ,    null  ) . % both numbers exhausted with a 0 carry: close the result.
add( f1 , null  , null  , f1(null) ) . % both numbers exhausted with a 1 carry: close the result.

% these clauses are the non-terminating special cases where we've
% exhausted the digits of one number, but not the other
add( f0 , null  , f0(Y) , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f0,null,Y,Z) . % 0+0   --> 0 carry 0
add( f0 , null  , f1(Y) , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f0,null,Y,Z) . % 0+1   --> 1 carry 0
add( f0 , f0(X) , null  , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,null,Z) . % 0+0   --> 0 carry 0
add( f0 , f1(X) , null  , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,null,Z) . % 0+1   --> 1 carry 0
add( f1 , null  , f0(Y) , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f0,null,Y,Z) . % 1+0   --> 1 carry 0
add( f1 , null  , f1(Y) , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f1,null,Y,Z) . % 1+1   --> 0 carry 1
add( f1 , f0(X) , null  , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,null,Z) . % 1+0   --> 1 carry 0
add( f1 , f1(X) , null  , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,null,Z) . % 1+1   --> 0 carry 1

% And these clauses are the general case, where we have digits from both numbers.
add( f0 , f0(X) , f0(Y) , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,Y,Z)    . % 0+0+0 --> 0 carry 0
add( f0 , f0(X) , f1(Y) , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,Y,Z)    . % 0+0+1 --> 1 carry 0
add( f0 , f1(X) , f0(Y) , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,Y,Z)    . % 0+1+0 --> 1 carry 0
add( f0 , f1(X) , f1(Y) , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f1,X,Y,Z)    . % 0+1+1 --> 0 carry 1
add( f1 , f0(X) , f0(Y) , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,Y,Z)    . % 1+0+0 --> 1 carry 0
add( f1 , f0(X) , f1(Y) , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f1,X,Y,Z)    . % 1+0+1 --> 0 carry 1
add( f1 , f1(X) , f0(Y) , f0(Z)    ) :- add(f0,X,Y,Z)    . % 1+1+0 --> 0 carry 1
add( f1 , f1(X) , f1(Y) , f1(Z)    ) :- add(f1,X,Y,Z)    . % 1+1+1 --> 1 carry 1
```